# Windows server 2003 mapping home drive wrong

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

first question...

we have around 30 servers in an Active Directory environment with 600 student computers and 100 staff desktops with XP SP2/3, the win server 2003 has the staff home drives on a NAS and in the last few days after some server updates is now mapping home drives to the \servername\home instead of \severname\home\%username%, its simple to re map the network drive but is annoying.

we dont use login script to map home drive but use a VB script for other network drives and if we add the home drive mapping to that it works, but shouldnt the profile option in users AD account map that correctly?

which do you all recommend, AD profile mapping or VB Script mapping Home drives?

thanks
Steven

Answer (score 1):

We use AD Profile Mapping via GPO for everything. VB Script/netlogon scripts are just too cumbersome to maintain, and there's *almost* nothing useful that they can do that a GPO can't.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer VB script mapping for everything as it gives you more control, and avoids situations like you've just experienced.  It's not that difficult to write a zero-maintenance drive mapping logon script if you plan your setup reasonably carefully - in our case home directories always go on H (My Docs is redirected to the same UNC, so we just read the My Docs redirection path and map to that, making it totally immune to server changes) and group directories go on I onwards; the UNC to the group directory is stashed in the group description so the logon script only needs to read that and map a drive.

In the 8 years since I wrote it I haven't had to update that script even once.

Answer (score 0):

I use AD profile mapping for home drives and scripts for just about everything else because my scripts do quite a lot of work, very little of which can readily be done through GPO.